# Ffmpeg Combine concatenate and filter command into one

Tags: video, ffmpeg

You can concatenate videos into one with

> ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4

with this in mylist.txt

> file '/path/to/file1.mp4'
>
> file '/path/to/file2.mp4'
>
> file '/path/to/file3.mp4'

I want to combine this with a regular command like trim or something else

> ffmpeg -i INPUT -vf trim=13:58 OUTPUT

I don't want to first export for example 3 files, each with their own filters and then concatenate those files to the final file.

Also each videos should be able to have their own filters.

Is this possible in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -vf trim=13:58 OUTPUT
```

*Also each videos should be able to have their own filters.*

Not possible, as such. You can't directly address the concat elements individually.

But if you know the duration of each video, you can employ trim filters to 'split' your input into individual constituents and then apply filters to those child streams. However, this is a convoluted and inefficient way to do this. Better to process each video individually.